# Changing style of commandlink title

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

When I try to inspect with firebug, i see nothing about the title of commandlink. So, how can 
 I change its style?

```
  <p:commandLink id="ajax" update="panel,display" 
   style="margin-right:20px;"  
  title="STYLE?">
  </p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood question correctly, but you can't edit this style! The title generated is a html component... Try to use something like it:

```
<p:tooltip for="ajax" >
    <h:outputText escape="false" value="<strong>Style?</strong>"/>  
</p:tooltip>
```

Now `commandlLink` title style can be modified. You can use a global tooltip too.